# How to test "if the width of the svg is bigger than the screen one"?

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I need to do a test to resize my SVG because I though by putting :

```
widht:100% !important  
height:100% !important
```

would make my SVG as I wanted a good idea but no it's not a good idea because when the SVG is small this code zoom on it and it's ugly.

here it's a small SVG:
[image]

and if I remove the CSS:
[image]

My goal is to have something to test the `widht` and if it's bigger than the actual one it resize it with `width:100% !important`

I have read about media query but I don't think it's what I need.

I hope you can understand my problem and help me a little bit or if you know how to solve this problem it's great too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `max-width:100%` and `height:auto` instead